# Why does a collection property can be changed without set?

Tags: c#, language-design

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace ConsoleApplication11
{

    class Customer
    {

        public List<string> Strings
        {
            get;

        } = new List<string>();
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Customer myCustomer = new Customer();
                myCustomer.Strings.Add("test");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

At last, the collection `Strings` can be added without `set` in property declaration. Why does c# design like that? It will be easier to understand if `collection` work just like ohter normal property, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is operating normally, you are not setting the property with that operation. `List<>` is an object, all you are doing is calling a method of that object already assigned to the `Strings` property.

If you were to do this instead:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Customer myCustomer = new Customer();
    myCustomer.Strings = new List<string>();
}
```

you will find that it won't compile because it is trying to assign a new value to a property that doesn't have a setter.

Answer (score -1):

Look at this line of code:

```
public List<string> Strings { get; } = new List<string>();
```

It may look like this code is saying that the property `Strings` holds a list of strings. But that's not actually true, because in C#, variables cannot contain objects. This code says that the property `Strings` holds a *reference* to a list of strings.

When you add elements to this list, you are not changing the value of the `Strings` property. You're modifying the object, but you're not modifying the reference. Since you're not changing the value of the `Strings` property, you don't need a setter.

Comment: I found this answer is a little disjointed and thus it's confusing.

Comment: @Enigmativity That's fair. Thanks for your feedback.